# Nodejs global object not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am using an angularjs front end with nodejs as the backend, and I am confused about why my `callobj` is not working as intended.

My relevant nodejs code is:

var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

```
var unirest = require('unirest');
var express = require("express");
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var o2x = require('object-to-xml');
var qs = require('querystring');
app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.get("/", function (req,res) {
    res.render('index.html');
});

var callobj = {};

app.post("/call", function(req,res){
    callobj.user = req.user;
    callobj.phone = req.phone;
    callobj.song = req.song;
    callobj.mp3link = req.mp3link;
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(callobj);
    res.send(200);
});

app.get("/call", function(req,res) {
    console.log(callobj);
    res.set("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    res.send(o2x({
        '?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?' : null,
        Response: {
                Play: callobj.mp3link
        }
    }));
});
```

The angularjs code is:

```
var app = angular.module('angularexpressApp', []);

app.controller('appController', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.user = 'Shawn';
  $scope.phone = '5197227689'
  $scope.song = 'Cant feel my face';
  $scope.mp3link = 'https://api.twilio.com/cowbell.mp3';
  $scope.mp3submit = function(){
    $http.post('/call', {user: $scope.user, phone: $scope.phone, song: $scope.song, mp3link: $scope.mp3link})
       .success(function(data){
           //what to do here
       })
       .error(function(data){
           console.log('Error: ' + data);
       });
     };
});
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Ya the problem wasn't with the global object, made a mistake sorry!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're assigning the `callobj` to the wrong values. It should be set to `req.body.<param>` if I recall correctly. The body of the request should contain the parameters you want.

Comment: The issue was that I needed to npm install body parser and use it in my express app, otherwise the req.body kept showing up as undefined. My bad!